# What is the best way to code a redirect to SSL page in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ssl, redirect

I have been struggling with redirecting to SSL page code for a while for a ASP.Net Application. I still have not found a good solution. The problem is that I want to have the code be disabled if I am on localhost for example when I am debugging or coding but I can not get it to work. Another issue is that it has to redirect to another url so http://www.xx.com should redirect to https://Secure.xxx.com. Any ideas?

Comment: Try  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site

Answer (score 5):

If you want the ssl property to be set at the page level, you should create a [custom attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sw480ze8%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
 public sealed class HttpsAttribute : Attribute{}

[HttpsAttribute]
public partial class PageSecured: YourCustomBasePage {}
```

Now the base page `YourCustomBasePage` can check if this `attribute` is set:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e){ 
   if(!Request.IsSecureConnection){
      HttpsAttribute secureAttribute = (HttpsAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(GetType(), typeof(HttpsAttribute));
      if(secureAttribute != null){
         //Build your https://Secure.xxx.com url
         UriBuilder httpsUrl = new UriBuilder(Request.Url){Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps, Port = 443};
         Response.Redirect(httpsUrl.Uri.ToString());
      }
   }
}
```

To exclude your local machine from redirecting to `HTTPS`, you can use a config value in your `web.config`.

```
private bool HTTPSEnabled{
  get{ return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTTPSEnabled"] == null || Boolean.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HTTPSEnabled"]); }
}
```

and you add the check to the first condition

```
if(!Request.IsSecureConnection && HTTPSEnabled)
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-security/WebPageSecurity_v2.aspx) library in production.  I prefer it to setting attributes because it is configuration driven, and configurable to a fine level.  That being said, I'm not sure if it can redirect to a subdomain.  I'm not even sure why you would want that to happen.