# IIS 7.5 HTTP to HTTPS redirect

Tags: web-config, iis-7.5, http-redirect

I am trying to have all HTTP requests redirect to HTTPS.
Here is my web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
    </system.webServer>


    <system.webServer>
       <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I found this sample in another post on Stackoverflow:
[How to force HTTPS using a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file)

When I save that file and try to access my site using http it does not redirect to https.

I thought that maybe the file was being ignored so I typed some incorrect syntax into the web.config then I got a 500 error- meaning that it is indeed looking at the web.config file.

Am I misunderstanding what the above configuration is supposed to do?  I want to redirect all HTTP request to HTTPS.

The site that is being redirected to is a virtual directory for Tomcat if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have URL Rewrite Installed.  [Click here for info/installation.](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)

Make sure you have the following configured within the URL Redirect in the IIS Manager.

**Match URL Section**

Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Regular Expressions
Pattern: (.*)

Make sure Ignore Case is checked

**Conditions Section**

Logical Grouping: Match All
Input: {HTTPS}
Type: Matches the Pattern
Pattern: ^OFF$

**Action Section**

Action type: Redirect

Action Properties

Redirect URL:  https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}
Make Sure 'Append Query String' is checked

Redirect Type: See other (303)

Comment: As far as I know the software that I'm doing this for cannot have URL rewrites.  Apache-Tomcat did not serve the ActiveX files for installation with the URL rewrite.

Comment: If there's third party software involved that must be mentioned in the first post in this thread along with any other important information.  The instructions above will redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this:

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```