# Redirect https to http using rewrite rule in webconfig file

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, url-rewriting

This is what I have tried so far.

```
 <rule name="https main site to http" stopProcessing="true">
       <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="true" />
       <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off" />
       </conditions>
       <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{REQUEST_URI}" />
 </rule>
```

How can I redirect https://www.mysite.com to http://www.mysite.com

Comment: How does it fail? Does nothing happen? Is the rule enabled in IIS?

Comment: Yes the rule is enabled in IIS

Answer (score 0):

This was asked a long time ago, but it looks like this has already been answered here: [How to force HTTPS using a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file).  Pay close attention to one of the comments that mentions that the query string is appended twice if you use the full answer.