# IIS Rewrite Rule in web.config to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I need to redirect all https requests to http, for example, if someone visits https://www.example.com/another-page/ to http://www.example.com/another-page/

I have the following rewrite rule in my web.config right now, but it's not working correctly. It's redirecting https://www.example.com/another-page/ to https://www.example.com/, so to the root of the site, but instead I want the redirect to stay in the same URL and only rewrite https to http.

```
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)" />
     <conditions>
       <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^onepage/(.*)$" negate="true" />
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
     </conditions>
     <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
```

Any help on changing the above rule so that it only changes https to http, but keeps the full url visited would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the use of `<add input="{R:1}" pattern="^onepage/(.*)$" negate="true" />`?

Comment: Extremely related, though this question is not technically a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file

Answer (score 18):

I set up your rule, cleaned up a little, and it worked; so this isn't really answering with much new.

Suggestion: Remove the `onepage` input condition just for testing, as cheesmacfly suggested in the question comment.

Also, try changing the action to `{R:1}` instead of `{R:0}`. It shouldn't matter in this case, but I just like using 1 and up, to match the specific capturing group. R:0 means the entire matched string, which always confuses me just a little.

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

One possibility is that your browser has cached a previous attempt of your rules. When the redirectType is Permanent, and you're still developing or testing, the browser often caches a previous rule. Clear your browser cache, and/or remove the Permanent, and/or browse in incognito mode. When done testing, change it to permanent. See number 2 and 3 in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204355/292060

Answer (score 3):

Please paste the below code in `web.config` file.

```
<rule name="Redirect to http" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTPS_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Comment: Thanks, but as stated in the question, site is running on IIS not Apache, so no .htaccess file.  Instead I'm using a web.config file and the IIS rewrite module.

Comment: I think you have misstyped HTTP and HTTPS. They must be reversed