# URL Rewrite from HTTPS to HTTPS

Tags: redirect, ssl, iis

I have a URL *   I need to redirect it to 
*
* is bound in IIS 8.0, but has no SSL certificate and we don't want to purchase one for cost reasons.
 is bound in IIS 8.0 and has an SSL certificate.

They are on the same site on the same server.  If someone comes to 
http://a.site.edu* they see the same site as if they came to http://a.nother.site.edu.  That's what we want.
If they come to https://a.nother.site.edu, that works as expected.
However, when they come to https://a.site.edu*, they get an error so we want to redirect them to https://a.nother.site.edu*  Can we redirect from 
https://a.site.edu* to https://a.nother.site.edu* without getting an error message? We are on Windows 2012 using IIS 8.0 with URL Rewrite 2.0 installed.
I have tried many types of configurations, but I always get a security error
something like this:

Secure Connection Failed

The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
```

Thanks for all replies.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IIS Rewrite Rule in web.config to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767014/iis-rewrite-rule-in-web-config-to-redirect-https-requests-to-http)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot redirect away from a SSL verification error because the SSL verification is done before the redirect happens. No workarounds.

Comment: Is it possible to redirect from https to http?  For example, could we redirect them https://a.site..edu to http://a.nother.site.edu?  Is that the same problem?  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: I just checked another entry and it appears to be the same problem.  Thanks again.