# is there any way to redirect IIS https request to http

Tags: iis

i have running website with https ..
"**SSL certificate is expired**"
is there any way to redirect all https request to http ?

Comment: Why not renew your SSL certificate instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS Rewrite Rule in web.config to redirect HTTPS requests to HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25767014/iis-rewrite-rule-in-web-config-to-redirect-https-requests-to-http)

Comment: Such redirection can be useless, as many browsers do stick to HTTPS. Besides, even if you have such redirection configured, the HTTPS error remains until you fix the certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Without considering the security of your website, just remove the Https binding and add an Http binding in the site binding module in IIS.
[image]
The website will work only over the HTTP protocol. Besides, Also, `IIS URL Rewrite Extension` is another choice to achieve this.

1. Install the `IIS URL Rewrite Extension`.
    [https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite](http://%20https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite)
2. Adding the below section in the `webconfig` file.

   ```
   <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
   <rule name="Force SSL (https)" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
        <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST} {REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" />
   ```

Finally, I strongly recommend that you renew your expired certificate. Nowadays Http is not supported in most of the browsers by default, such as Google Chrome, Safari. Moreover, it is not security, can easily disclose certain private information by Fiddler, some Http traffic capture tool.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Dai suggested above i would go for renewing SSL certificate. You can use Free SSL cerficates like [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). But if you want Https to Http redirection (I won't recommend Https to Http) you can use [IIS url rewrite extension](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9953/38/iis-redirect-http-to-https)