# Web API 2 RequireHttps allowing http connection

Tags: https, asp.net-web-api2

I have created the following action in my MVC Web API 2 controller:

```
    [ResponseType(typeof(int))]
    [RequireHttps]
    public IHttpActionResult SaveLead(EcommerceLead lead)
    {
    }
```

But in my test app I am making a call to

```
http://localhost/api/savelead
```

And it is working.  Is there any way to make the action to only work if it is called over https, ie return a 404 if it isn't or something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using `RequireHttps` from Mvc namespace, it will not work with Web API. You can write a simple filter for Web API yourself to enforce HTTPS. Since you are using Web API 2, create an authentication filter like this.

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : IAuthenticationFilter
{
    public bool AllowMultiple
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public Task AuthenticateAsync(HttpAuthenticationContext context, 
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (context.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            context.ActionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(
                                    System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

        }
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    public Task ChallengeAsync(HttpAuthenticationChallengeContext context,
                                        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Badri: I have your book (Pro ASP.Net Web Api security) and also Web API 2 Recipes book by Filip Wojcieszyn which cites your book. He presents a solution almost identical to what you have outlined above and I found an action filter implementation in your book. My question is: I found that the AuthenticationFilter worked for all my controllers except on which implements only a POST endpoint. In order to enforce HTTPS to the POST endpoint I could use an action filter but when using the AuthenticationFilter the call still goes to POST method. Any insights on what might be going on?

Comment: For it to work, I had to make the class derive from Attribute, i.e.: public class RequireHttpsAttribute : Attribute, IAuthenticationFilter

Comment: This didn't work for me. I tracked down the problem to the way the error response is set. `context.ActionContext.Response` needs to instead be `context.ErrorResult`. see docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/authentication-filters

Answer (score 2):

If you are using web api older version you can use Authoriztion filter.

```
public class RequireHttpsAttribute : AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
        {
            actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
            };
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use Message Handler.

public class RequireHttpsHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
if (request.RequestUri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
{
return Task.FromResult(new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
{
ReasonPhrase = "HTTPS Required"
});
}
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
}
}
```