# How to make a website work only with https

Tags: asp.net, ssl, https

How do I make a website to work only with https? Is there any method to make my website work only if the protocol is https?

For example let me say http://www.mywebsite.com, this should work only with https://www.mywebsite.com, if it's http the website should not be accessible .

Is it possible to make a website work only with https? Is it possible to restrict a website /make a website inaccessible if the website was http?

Comment: You can create a rule in the config file which redirects users from http to https

Comment: This question shows how to redirect http to https in web.config http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, assuming you are using IIS to host your site, open IIS Manager and select your web site and then binding on the right:

[image]

make sure you only have a binding for `https` not for `http`.

This way IIS will only send https traffic to that web site.

**Edit:** What is the difference between Andre's answer `Require SSL` and mine?

using `Require SSL`, when users requesting `http://` they will get a:

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

When using only an https binding, no connection is made at all and the user eventually gets:

> ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

It's up to you which option you prefer.

I usually have a catch-all site on all servers that respond to any requests not picked up by real sites and just displays a basic 404 page.

The third option is to actually allow http:// but then redirect to https:// as mentioned in the comments. For that solution you have to install the URL rewrite module and add a redirect rule.

My single binding option is the leanest, but it all depends on how you want you site to handle http:// requests.

Answer (score 1):

Create Rule in your web.config which will force to open in https only as shown below

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

For IIS? Start the IIS Manager, click on your site and double click "SSL Settings" and check "Require SSL".

What I have done using Apache: add redirect from http to https