# SSL on Asp.net website

Tags: asp.net, ssl

i'm mainting a 5 years old asp.net based website for a client. now i'm suggesting him to add SSL on the website. our web hosting company said they will do it for us with a extra fee.  (they using GEO trust ssl certificate).

my question is do i have to change anything in my asp.net application if web hosting company enable the SSL from dere side?

website is been hosted on shared server?

Comment: No, you dont need to change anything. But for SSL, then you need to purchase SSL and static IP from your hosting provider.

Answer (score 1):

Your asp.net app doesn't have to be aware of ssl certificate, nor you have to change anything in the code. But, you should add routing rules to redirect all http requests to https endpoint, with asp.net routing (in web.config or in iis if you have access, but since its shared hosting then no I guess).
SSL are quite cheap now, price going from 6-7$/year/domain for the cheapest one (no company verification, etc), or even free with LetsEncrypt (I'm using that one with asp.net, but it needs to be renewed every 3 months!)

Comment: this answer explains how to add redirect to HTTPS to your web.config: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file