# Azure web app not redirecting http to https even after web.config

Tags: azure, ssl, web-config

I have a azure web app which uses custom domain from godaddy.

I got the SSL certificate from namecheap.com and applied binding to 
both mathanka.com and www.mathanka.com
When i enter manually it works fine. I used web.config with below mentioned rules.

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
<staticContent>
  <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="1.00:00:00" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

but its not redirecting to https://
url : mathanka.com

Please guide me the solution and step to take.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it an ASP.Net MVC app?

Comment: No sir. it is just static website built on html and javascript. hosted on azure web app.

Comment: To mention,  the rule which i mentioned above is working at some cases. for example, in chrome, Even after clearing cookies and history, when i first load. https is not appearing. but when i again reload with ctrl + R. then it appears with https:

my doubts is even though we clear all cookies and history why its not appearing in first load?



Awaiting for the solution

Thanks,

Comment: Did you get the solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This is the copy\paste from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file).

Comment: I already tried this code. its not working. it still directs to http site only