# HTTPS redirect in .htaccess is causing infinite redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess, iis

I'm trying to redirect all HTTP urls to HTTPS using the following in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However it just causes an infinite redirect loop.  There is a valid SSL certificate and the website is written in asp.net in case it matters.  Google chrome automatically redirects to https, but firefox and edge do not so I need to add this rule.  The only way I can get the site to load in https is if I explicitly type https:// in the address.  What's the possible cause here?

Comment: @anubhava This is IIS

Comment: Are you using "Helicon Ape" on IIS? What is your TLD?

Comment: IIS does not support `.htaccess` at all, so I  wonder why you attempted to use that. Any background you missed here?

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not support .htaccess file.so I suggest you use iis URL rewrite module and add a rule using that.

for that, you need to install the URL rewrite module by using the web platform installer or from this below link.

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

than add below code in your config file:

```
<configuration>
 <system.webServer>
 <rewrite>
 <rules>
 <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent"/>
 </rule>
 </rules>
 </rewrite>
 </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

for more detail you could refer this below link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/55531655/11147346

Answer (score -1):

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://yourwebsite.com/$1 [R,L]`

try that

or use cloudflare to cache and perfomace your project
https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000219871-Troubleshooting-redirect-loop-errors
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-flexible-ssl-is-it-worth-it/28043
https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/origin/ssl-modes/