# IIS URL HTTP to HTTPS redirect not working on ASP.Net application

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, plesk

I have an ASP.Net application being hosted on a webserver with Plesk installed.

The application is hosted on a sub-domain (webapp.website.com) and the link to login to the system is supplied through the main domain website, so I haven't noticed this up until now.

If you type in `webapp.website.com` or `http://webapp.website.com` the website will connect to an unsecured page with the following error:

> Server Error
> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.
> You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

If you manually type in `https://webapp.website.com` (which is what the link is setup to do) the app connects just fine and works as expected.

I have enabled Permanent Redirect to HTTPS in Plesk, and have manually written a redirect rule in IIS Manager, but for some reason it seems to be ignoring this rule because the server connection is failing in HTTP and displaying the Server Error page instead.

How can I resolve the redirect issue to either stop the error on HTTP, or for it to skip over and redirect to HTTPS?

Comment: Did you create a correct rewrite rule? See my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/45846372/5836671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect there may be a problem with your rules, you can try the following rules:

```
      <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Test" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="OFF" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

This rule will redirect all http requests to https.