# MVC 5: Handling .html Page Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

MVC uses `.cshtml` for the view pages. I want to combine with `.html` pages.

The problem if I put `index.html` in the navigation, it will bypass all the redirection process and will just load `index.html` directly. This raises a problem when I encrypt my website within SSL/TLS, the resulting page will be just in `http://` not `https://`.

Is there a way I can control so the `.html` page redirect is encrypted in SSL/TLS?

Answer (score 0):

If the .html pages are local, why not just enforce https only?

[How to force HTTPS using a web.config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file)

Comment: Im hosting it on shared hosting, i have no controll of the IIS