# How can I configure unleash toggle server to work over HTTPS within Azure App Service?

Tags: node.js, toggle

Unleash documentation can be found here: https://unleash.github.io/docs/getting_started

There are resources available to "secure" unleash but no mention of running unleash over HTTPS. I have created an authentication middleware hook, but if I can't deploy over HTTPS client credentials would be sent encrypted - which is unacceptable.

I want unleash to run as a web app in Azure App Service. How can I configure this as intended?

Answer (score 1):

By default, Unleash runs on port 4242. The unleash start function allows you to customize port numbers like so:

```
  unleash
  .start({
    databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    port: {CUSTOM}
  })
  .then(unleash => {
    console.log(
      `Unleash started on port ${unleash.app.get('port')}`,
    );
  });
```

However, if you set port to 443 for HTTPS support, Azure app service will throw an error that the command does not have permission to run at that port:

```
 EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:443
```

## **The solution lies in Azure's process.env.PORT variable:**

If you output the value of process.env.PORT you will see a dynamic value such as:

```
\\.\pipe\fc1ef0b7-c1ce-4186-f9d8-fd0b5b0f6d0a
```

Azure is setting a named pipe in the env that Unleash can use as its "port". Therefore, the proper unleash setup would be as follows:

```
  unleash
  .start({
    databaseUrl: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    pipe: process.env.PORT 
  })
  .then(unleash => {
    console.log(
      `Unleash started on port ${unleash.app.get('port')}`,
    );
  });
```

Notice the option of "pipe" rather than "port" as a parameter for "start". Do not specify the "port" option in this case. Unleash documentation provides more insight into how the pipe works with node [here](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_identifying_paths_for_ipc_connections).

P.S. One can also benefit from a [web.config rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9823010/how-to-force-https-using-a-web-config-file) that redirects all http connections to https.