# how to always do a https request to a website hosted on microsoft azure

Tags: azure

I get "504 gateway" error when I do a "http://xyz.com" request for a website hosted on azure.  However, if I do a "https://xyz.com" request for the same website I get the webpage.  How do I always do a https request for this URL even if somebody forgets to do https

Answer (score 0):

Found this in StackOverflow
[Best way in asp.net to force https for an entire site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site)

And I think URL Rewrite or Http Module might help as well.