# How to use urlrouting with https

Tags: asp.net, url-routing, webforms

I'm using url routing for my latest project - it's web forms not MVC.

I noticed that all paths to physical pages are virtual, so how do I direct to an https page?

Comment: have a look [URL Routing with ASP.NET 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET-4-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to redirect to HTTPS. See the answers on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site).

You can add a [UrlRewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) rule to IIS (or directly to the web.config like below):

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect HTTP to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. I only want to redirect 1 page, not the entire site. I'm also worried about conflict between routing and urlrewriting?

Comment: You can put this code on the page you want to redirect to https:  `if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection.Equals(false) && HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal.Equals(false))
   {
    Response.Redirect("https://" + Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"]
+   HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl);
   }`