# Redirecting from http to https from server side

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a webpage which uses https. If a user changes the url For instance: https://www.abc.com/page1.aspx to http://www.abc.com/page1.aspx.

I can know through the code i.e. Request.IsSecureConnection that whether the connection is secured or not. My question is that if the user has input http url. So how can I redirect it to https through server side code in VB.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best way in asp.net to force https for an entire site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site)

Answer (score 0):

you can `Replace` the `HTTP` by `HTTPS`... Try like below it will help you..

```
    If (Request.IsSecureConnection = False) Then
        Dim Url As String
        Url = Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http:", "https:")
        Response.Redirect(Url)
    End If
```