# How do I force ASP.NET app to use HTTPS?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, ssl, https

My app uses HTTPS only.  I have SSL enabled from the properties window. Everything works well except, when I run the project, it runs on HTTP.  I then have to

- change the URL manually to HTTPS, and then
- change the port number to the SSL one.

How can I force the app to run as HTTPS?  Is there a quick fix for that (without using logic in my pages)?  I searched for this, but I haven't found a case that matches mine.

*Note: I am using ASP.NET MVC4 with web API.*

Comment: Have you added the RequireHttps attribute to any of your controllers or actions?

Comment: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Redirect-from-HTTP-to-HTTPS-in-Asp-Net-WebForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to detect if the request came in http or https, and redirect if http to https.  The below post should have some hints

[Best way in asp.net to force https for an entire site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47089/best-way-in-asp-net-to-force-https-for-an-entire-site)