# OWIN and Azure AD HTTPS to HTTP Redirect Loop

Tags: azure, redirect, owin

I am very new to OWIN :).  I am trying to have a page with an open public area which will allow anonymous over HTTP, and then a restricted section which will require authentication.  I'd like not to force the entire site to be HTTPS for general users.

The issue I have is that I receive the following loop:

1. http://example.com/authenticatedPage -> 302 Redirect to AD login
2. Login to AD page HTTP 200.  Triggers open of the Azure AD link to site.
3. Link to site identifies that this is an OWIN redirect and does a 302 redirect to http://example.com/authenticatedPage
4. Go to 1.

I have tried 3 ways of intercepting the redirect in OWIN but nothing seems to work.

If I begin the session by browsing to https://example.com/ then click on the link to authenticatedPage, then the login works as I expect. i.e.

1. Load https://example.com/authenticatedPage -> 302 redirect to AD
2. Login to AD -> loads https://example.com/
3. 302 redirect to https://example.com/authenticatedPage

Is there anyway to fix this without marking my whole site as requiring SSL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I haven't introduced a gaping security hole, this actually worked.  Override the authorize attribute and apply this to your controller.  If you try to authorise from an insecure page, it will redirect you to the HTTPS:// of the page first, prior to attempting authentication.  THis means the redirect from Azure will then redirect back to HTTPS and it works like a charm.  Cookies stay secure and everyone's a winner!

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Spenceee.Attributes
{
    public class AuthorizeFromHTTPAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection)
            {
                UriBuilder redirectUrl = new UriBuilder(
                   filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url);
                redirectUrl.Scheme = "HTTPS";
                redirectUrl.Port = 443;
                filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(redirectUrl.ToString());
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is the referrer set by the OIDC middleware in your application. What happens is this:

1. Enter your application on http://foo.bar and redirect to Identity provider
2. The IDP/AD redirects to https://foo.bar as configured return URI
3. Cookie is set by OIDC middleware with Secure flag so for HTTPS only
4. Middleware redirects to referrer URL which was HTTP
5. Cookie is not set on HTTP, so back to step 1.

There are multiple solutions to this such as enforcing SSL only, overloading the Authorize attribute and setting the `CookieSecure` flag to `CookieSecureOption.Never` (don't do this).

The option I prefer is to fix the Referrer in the middleware itself as such:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
{
    Authority = ...
    ClientId = ...
    RedirectUri = "https://foo.bar"
    ResponseType = "id_token",
    Scope = "openid profile",      
    SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

    // Deal with the returning tokens
    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
    {
        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
        {
            // Enforce the reference/redirect to be HTTPS
            var builder = new UriBuilder(n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri);
            builder.Scheme = "https";
            builder.Port = 443;
            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = builder.ToString();
        }
    }
});
```

What this does is rewrite the HTTP on the Referrer URL to HTTPS. This way if the user enters the app on HTTP, he'll be automatically redirected to a HTTPS version after using it.

Comment: So you've updated OWIN/your middleware to do this prior to the redirect.  Reasonable solution with open source.  I was trying to avoid maintaining a fork on the open source, but still a reasonable solution.

Comment: @Spence this does not require any changes to any open source software or forks. The notification and AuthorizationCodeReceived handler already are implemented by Microsoft in their standard middleware.

Comment: Not obvious in my question, but I'm logging into the Azure Active Directory, that's not using OpenID authentication.  The code for that is not as extensible as the open id stuff from what I can tell.  this question is also nearly a year old so all the frameworks have moved forward.  Also the redirect comes from Azure, not my code.

Comment: AAD supports OIDC. It is actually their recommended way of authenticating. It is indeed not as extensible as AAD doesn't allow custom scopes for now (unless you are an AAD administrator and set the permissions for your app). Frameworks moved forward indeed, consuming middleware is largely the same. Regarding the redirects, yes they do come from Azure to your host but your host then sets the cookie and redirects to itself again to the referrer specified. The redirect to itself is where the problem is in your original question.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a specific reason for which you don't want to mark the entire site as requiring SSL? There might be ways around the above, but they might be risky. If you expect to have a session cookie for your domain at some point, you want to make sure that it is never sent around without a proper secure channel... and handling the switching between the two is tricky. If you can share the reasons for which you are reluctant in using SSL for the entire app, that would be super useful for us... our current assumption is that it is viable, and so far it seemed to pan out, but there might be something we are overlooking.

Comment: Hosted on azure. Extra charges for SSL. I just wanted to have a staff link at the top of the page which authenticates to make it easy for the team

Comment: Thanks for the extra context. I haven't been working with Azure pricing lately, but until some time ago you would pay the same amount regardless of how many routes use SSL... in other words, the only difference was between using SSL or not using it at all. I will ask around to understand if that has changed...

Answer (score 0):

As Vittorio suggests, forcing the entire site to use SSL fixes the issue. Assuming that is a viable scenario for you, just add a global filter in the `Application_Start` method of `Global.asax.cs`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new RequireHttpsAttribute());
        ...
```

Users can now walk up to your app using either HTTP or HTTPS and will be re-routed correctly after authentication without the infinite redirect loop.

Comment: Understand your point.  As I was using Azure hosting, not requiring SSL for my public page which has nothing on it that needs security would save money, I wanted to avoid this.  I did find a reasonable solution but I'm surprised it was as hard as it was to do.

Comment: Glad you were able to find a reasonable solution, and unfortunately not surprised that it was hard.