# Identity Server 3 After login looping issue

Tags: c#, owin, identityserver3, openid-connect

We have issue with the following code

```html
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Subject;
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            app.Map("/identity", idsrvApp =>
            {
                idsrvApp.UseIdentityServer(new IdentityServerOptions
                {
                    SiteName = "Authentication Server",
                    SigningCertificate = LoadCertificate(),
                    IssuerUri = "https://localhost:44305/",
                    Factory = new IdentityServerServiceFactory()
                                .UseInMemoryUsers(Users.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryClients(Clients.Get())
                                .UseInMemoryScopes(Scopes.Get()),
                    //EnableWelcomePage = false,
                    RequireSsl = true,
                    AuthenticationOptions = new IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.AuthenticationOptions
                    {
                        EnablePostSignOutAutoRedirect = true,
                        IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
                    },
                });
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                Authority = "https://localhost:44305/identity",
                RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44305/",
                ClientId = "mvc",
                Scope = "openid",
                ResponseType = "id_token token",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                UseTokenLifetime = false,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                    {
                        var nid = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType,
                            IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.GivenName,
                            IdentityServer3.Core.Constants.ClaimTypes.Role);

                        // get userinfo data
                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                            new Uri(n.Options.Authority + "/connect/userinfo"),
                            n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);

                        var userInfo = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();
                        userInfo.Claims.ToList().ForEach(ui => nid.AddClaim(new Claim(ui.Item1, ui.Item2)));

                        // keep the id_token for logout
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                        // add access token for sample API
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", n.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken));

                        // keep track of access token expiration
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTimeOffset.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(n.ProtocolMessage.ExpiresIn)).ToString()));

                        // add some other app specific claim
                        nid.AddClaim(new Claim("app_specific", "some data"));

                        n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            nid,
                            n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                        var data = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Identity;
                        
                    },

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                    {
                        if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            }
                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },
                }
            });

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "Cookies",
                            });

            
        }

        public static X509Certificate2 LoadCertificate()
        {
            return new X509Certificate2(
                string.Format(@"{0}\bin\identityServer\idsrv3test.pfx", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory), "idsrv3test");
        }
```

Issue is like when login successed that time identity goes to looping.

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to access the site in the first place? I think you are accessing it over HTTP. The result is a cookie problem that is set for HTTPS and not HTTP and it will keep trying to redirect to itself.

I explained this in depth with an answer here: [OWIN and Azure AD HTTPS to HTTP Redirect Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31588552/owin-and-azure-ad-https-to-http-redirect-loop/39168646#39168646)

Comment: I am using Asp.net WebFroms and Identity Server 3.Webconfig set authorization and its directly go for Identity Server login page and after login successed its not work.

Comment: The technology is not really relevant. It should work with any of them. Take a look at the linked answer.

Comment: Same structure works into MVC side.its working fine in MVC